# Clase String en java?

Tags: java, string

Hola amigos estoy estudiando java y ví que en java no existe el tipo de dato primitivo "String" sino que existe la "clase String "porque?  ,que es un tipo de dato referenciado a un objeto pero mi otra pregunta es porque dicen que es una clase y luego veo que el String es un objetoM

Comment: Copiando un comentario que he hecho en una pregunta anterior tuya: Hola Gilberto, te pediría que por favor cuides de la ortografía y la puntuación en tus preguntas. De lo contrario, puede dificultar su lectura. Gracias.

Comment: Sorry estoy con el móvil y con su aplicación android

Comment: Quizás, pero eso no te impide de verificar la calidad de la pregunta antes de publicarla. Hacer este tipo de esfuerzo en la calidad de la pregunta es una manera de dignificar la comunidad que da de su tiempo libre para contestar las preguntas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola el dato primitivo para caracteres es char y como sabras el char solo es posible usar un solo caracter 'a', 'b', 'c', la clase String envuelve por así decirlo al tipo de dato char y hace posible que puedas formar cadenas  "cadenaDeCaracteres".

Tomando esto en cuenta el objeto es la variable que declaras de la clase String:

```
String miObjetoCadena = new String();  
String miObjetoCadena2="";  
String miObjetoCadena3="Stack Over";  
String miObjetoCadena4= new String ("Stack Over");
```

Comment: Mil gracias estaba pensando algo así la verdad una pregunta? Si como dices aquí " tomando esto en cuenta el objeto es la variable que declaras de la clase string" eso se podría si fuera un int o booleano o si no es posible como se podría hacer?

Comment: Si existen las clases llamadas Wrapper Class, por ej la clase que envuelve al tipo int es Integer, al float es Float, recuerda que la clase es por asi decirlo la plantilla de un objeto, es Decir la clase Describe que tiene como sus variables globales o atributos y metodos (comportamiento) y el objeto es la variable que se crea de esa clase (plantilla).

Comment: @gilbertoquintero *la clase String envuelve por así decirlo al tipo de dato char y hace posible que puedas formar cadenas "cadenaDeCaracteres"* es mitad cierto mitad no. La clase `String` en su interior tiene un arreglo de caracteres, es decir un `char[]`. No te diría que envuelve un `char` o grupo de `char`s porque la clase que hace eso es `Character`. `String` es una representación de una cadena de caracteres concreta. A diferencia de muchas clases, Java facilita el trabajo con `String`s como si fuesen primitivos (p.e. puedes usar `+` con `String`) pero sus instancias siguen siendo objetos.